# bs4 script return no errors but does not execute the code

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i've written a small parser to get the content of 5 web-pages, i run it and it executes without error and give me `Process finished with exit code 0`, but nothing happens – i have a writer within the script that should create a .csv and write the data there, but my script has no output, it just executes and terminates in silence with exit code 0. have never encountered such thing, any ideas?

the structure of the web-page is like that - the tag `row mb-2` contains all div tags with listings:

```
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="grid-block col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-2 px-0 px-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="grid-block col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-2 px-0 px-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="grid-block col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-2 px-0 px-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="grid-block col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-2 px-0 px-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

the code of the script looks like that:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

u_list = ['https://www.landcentury.com/search/page-1?categories%5B0%5D=commercial-and-industrial-land&options%5B0%5D=for-sale',
        'https://www.landcentury.com/search/page-2?categories%5B0%5D=commercial-and-industrial-land&options%5B0%5D=for-sale',
        'https://www.landcentury.com/search/page-3?categories%5B0%5D=commercial-and-industrial-land&options%5B0%5D=for-sale',
        'https://www.landcentury.com/search/page-4?categories%5B0%5D=commercial-and-industrial-land&options%5B0%5D=for-sale',
        'https://www.landcentury.com/search/page-5?categories%5B0%5D=commercial-and-industrial-land&options%5B0%5D=for-sale']

for url in range(0, 5):
    page = requests.get(u_list[url])
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

    landplots = soup.find_all('div', class_='row mb-2')

    for l in landplots:
        row = []
        try:
            plot_price = l.find('div', class_= 'price ').find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True)
            plot_location = l.find('div', class_ = 'card-title').find_next(text=True).text
            plot_square = l.find('div', class_ = 'card-title').find_next(text=True).get_text(strip=True)

            row.append(plot_price)
            row.append(plot_location)
            row.append(plot_square)

            print(plot_price)
            print(plot_square)
            print(plot_location)
            print()
        except AttributeError:
            continue


        with open("parsing_second.csv", 'a', newline = '') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: there is no `preview__size` class

Comment: This will happen if *soup.find_all('div', class_='row mb-2')* returns an empty list

Comment: @AlbertWinestein that is not the case, i tried printing that now and it printed out the content of the page just fine.

Comment: @SergeyK that's my typo, but generally all those `divs` i am looping through are within items general div tags, i just did not expose the html structure up to the text levels for the sake of my question being compact

Comment: @elarednax In that case you're probably getting AttributeError on every iteration of landplots in which case *row* will be empty. Put a *print* in the *except* block

Comment: @AlbertWinestein yeah that helped, there is indeed some attribute error. probably some problem with price tag, as when i copy it from the html section i've inspected in the browser it contains a space and looks like that: "price  ", but when the script prints me soup.find_all(.....) and i look for price tag in that print, the price goes without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you need fields - price, square and location. I suggest using Pandas to save to a file. This will allow you more flexibility in choosing the format in the future.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


results = []
for page in range(0, 5):
    url = f'https://www.landcentury.com/search/page-{page}?categories%5B0%5D=commercial-and-industrial-land&options%5B0%5D=for-sale'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    for card in soup.find_all('div', class_='listing-item'):
        price = card.find('div', class_='price').getText(separator=' ').strip()
        square, location = card.find('div', class_='card-title').getText(separator='/').split('/')
        data = {
            'Price': price,
            'Square': square,
            'Location': location
        }
        results.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('landcentury.csv', index=False)
```

CSV RESULT:

[image: CSV]

Comment: that helped, thank you for suggesting pandas! however, it only parses 160 lines, but i suppose that's how many items they have on 5 pages

Comment: yep 5 pages contains only 160 rows, btw you can collect links - `link = card.find('a').get('href').strip()`  mb you might find it useful

Comment: that's nice! saved links as well, thank you! :)